# When upgrading contracts can you change the logic inside functions?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, upgrading, proxy-contracts, contract-upgrading

I am trying to wrap my head around all this and am looking for someone to help clarify.

Lets say I have the following:

```js
contract Test {
    public c = 3;
    function A(uint a) returns(uint){
    
       uint b = a - c;
       return b;
    }
    
    function B() returns(uint){
       return b + a;
    }
    
}
```

Now I have found a bug in my code and function `A` should be this:

```js
contract Test {
    public c = 3;
    function A(uint a) returns(uint){

       uint b = a - C();
       return b;
    }

    function B() returns(uint){
       return b + a;
    }
    
    function C() returns(uint) {
       return c * 2;
    }
}
```

Would this work in with upgrading proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you are using the [proxy delegate](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/the-state-of-smart-contract-upgrades/) pattern, your upgrade would work!

One important rule is to avoid overwriting your state. So, in your case, your contracts would break if you added a new variable on the line *before* `public c = 3;`.